# Alter Unique Constraint in PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

I have a table called addresses with a unique constraint on two fields: (address, and hostname). I realized I need to add 1 more field to the constraint. I have a piece of row I need to insert with equal address and hostname but not coin_id. When trying to insert I get this.

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "address_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (address, hostname)=(GfFrqCJtwuSSJyv6D1STtrT146N8p9cLtd, NHWithdrawal) already exists.
SQL state: 23505
```

I have tried viewing my constraints with the following:

```
select * from information_schema.table_constraints
where constraint_type = 'UNIQUE'
```

I am not able to see the address_uniq constraint in that list.

How can I do the following:

1. Locate this constraint with psql
2. Alter/Update this constraint, and add 1 more column to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [How can I] Locate this constraint with psql

We can get the same error message if we violate a primary key constraint.

```
# alter table addresses add constraint addresses_pk primary key (id);
ALTER TABLE
# insert into addresses values (1, 2, 4, 4);
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "addresses_pk"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
#
```

Try searching the information schema `where constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'`.

Note that we don't have to give a primary key constraint a name, as Postgres will generate a default of `<table_name>_pkey`. So for this to be the solution in your case it means  whoever created the primary key gave it an explicit name of `address_uniq`, which would be confusing.

So a more likely possibility is that you have a unique index on those columns. Indexes don't show up in the information schema. You can check like this:

```
select * from pg_indexes where tablename = 'addresses';
```

> [How can I] Alter/Update this constraint, and add 1 more column to it

If your problem is an index  then do this:

```
# drop index address_uniq;
DROP INDEX
# create unique index address_uniq on addresses (address, hostname, coin_id);
CREATE INDEX
#
```

If it turns out it is a primary key constraint it's a similar process:

```
# alter table addresses drop constraint address_uniq;
ALTER TABLE
# alter table addresses add constraint address_uniq primary key (address, hostname,coin_id);
ALTER TABLE
#
```

Comment: *You will get the same error message if you violate a primary key constraint.* No. The error message contains the unique constraint name.

Comment: @klin - um, yes. Assuming whoever created the primary key gave it an explicit name of `address_uniq`

Comment: It's more likely that the OP doesn't have sufficient privileges on the table.

Comment: @APC was correct. This constraint did not show up in information schema but it did in pg_indexes

Answer (score 3):

Your constraint_type should also be "PRIMARY KEY" so the best way to locate 
the constraint is using constraint_name.

```
select * from information_schema.table_constraints where constraint_name = 'address_uniq'
```

You can drop the existing constraint

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name DROP CONSTRAINT address_uniq;
```

and add a new one:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name ADD CONSTRAINT address_uniq PRIMARY KEY(address, hostname, coin_id);
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name ADD CONSTRAINT address_uniq UNIQUE(address, hostname, coin_id);
```

Comment: Your initial query did not return any rows